# How to add labels in provinces in Google Geochart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts in Angular4 
https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart

example provinces chart:

```
  public map_ChartData = [
    ['Provinces',   'Popularity'],
         [{ v: 'NL-DR', f: 'Drenthe' },  5],
         [{ v: 'NL-NH', f: 'Noord-Holland' },  1000],
         [{ v: 'NL-UT', f: 'Utrecht' },  800],
         [{ v: 'NL-FL', f: 'Flevoland' },  200],
         [{ v: 'NL-FR', f: 'Friesland' },  350],
         [{ v: 'NL-GE', f: 'Gelderland' },  450],
         [{ v: 'NL-GR', f: 'Groningen' },  788],
         [{ v: 'NL-LI', f: 'Limburg' },  244],
         [{ v: 'NL-NB', f: 'Noord-Brabant' },  750],
         [{ v: 'NL-OV', f: 'Overijssel' },  620],
         [{ v: 'NL-ZE', f: 'Zeeland' },  50],
         [{ v: 'NL-ZH', f: 'Zuid-Holland' },  890]
      ];

  public map_ChartOptions = {
    region: 'NL', resolution: 'provinces',
    colorAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 1000,      
      colors: ['grey', 'yellow', 'orange', 'blue', 'green']
    }};


<div id="map_chart" 
(itemSelect)="itemSelected($event)" 
(itemDeselect)="itemDeselected($event)" 
[chartData]="map_ChartData"
[chartOptions]="map_ChartOptions" 
chartType="GeoChart" 
GoogleChart></div>
```

[image]

Is it possible to display the name and value in province besides in the tooltip?

**UPDATE**
Using this shows an empty map:

```
  public map_ChartOptions = {
    region: 'NL', resolution: 'provinces', displayMode: 'text',
    colorAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 1000,      
      colors: ['grey', 'yellow', 'orange', 'blue', 'green']
    }};
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

I was missing to get an API key for Google Maps at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#step-1-get-an-api-key-from-the-google-api-console and include

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using option --> `displayMode: 'text'` -- will apply labels
the labels are slow to load but do appear...

however, this will also move the colors to the labels,
and remove the background color from the provinces...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['geochart'],
  mapsApiKey: 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Provinces',   'Popularity'],
    [{ v: 'NL-DR', f: 'Drenthe' },  5],
    [{ v: 'NL-NH', f: 'Noord-Holland' },  1000],
    [{ v: 'NL-UT', f: 'Utrecht' },  800],
    [{ v: 'NL-FL', f: 'Flevoland' },  200],
    [{ v: 'NL-FR', f: 'Friesland' },  350],
    [{ v: 'NL-GE', f: 'Gelderland' },  450],
    [{ v: 'NL-GR', f: 'Groningen' },  788],
    [{ v: 'NL-LI', f: 'Limburg' },  244],
    [{ v: 'NL-NB', f: 'Noord-Brabant' },  750],
    [{ v: 'NL-OV', f: 'Overijssel' },  620],
    [{ v: 'NL-ZE', f: 'Zeeland' },  50],
    [{ v: 'NL-ZH', f: 'Zuid-Holland' },  890]
  ]);

  var options = {
    displayMode: 'text',
    region: 'NL',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    colorAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 1000,
      colors: ['grey', 'yellow', 'orange', 'blue', 'green']
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Ah. `displayMode: "text"' is indeed the answer.  What I was missing was to get an API Key for Google Maps. After I got it and activated it the labels were showing.